# Hiding addToCart Button and then displaying it at the center of the product when hover over

Tags: css, material-ui, next.js

I have this add to cart button, that I can hide it, and I want to display it at the center of the product Image when hover over it.
Am using Nextjs with material ui element, I try to display it on the middle by assigning top: value, it didn't work I try margin bottom  also it didn't work.
The problem is the addToCart Button don't even go up to the image part, it literaly stays within the card space below the image... here is the component

```
<Card className={classes.card}>
  <CardActionArea className={classes.cardArea}>
  <CardMedia className={classes.cardMedia}
        component="img"
        image={product.image}
        title={product.name}
      >
      </CardMedia>
      <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
      <NextLink href={`/product/${product.slug}`} passHref>
      <Link>
      <Typography>{product.name}</Typography>
      </Link>
      </NextLink>
      <Typography>${product.price}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </CardActionArea>
  <CardActions>
  </CardActions>
  <div className={classes.addTocart}>
  <Button
  fullWidth
  size="large"
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  onClick={() => addToCartHandler(product)}>
  Add to cart
</Button>
  </div>
</Card>
```

Any Idea type of styles I can give to it using styles.js

below are my styles component

```
      cardContent: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  addToCart: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  addToCartButton: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 80,
  }
}));
```

Below is the current project am working on
[Here is my current project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCCdA.jpg)

And Here is the link to similar of what I want to do
In this link you will notice how the button add to cart get display when you hover over it...
[Example of what I want to Imitate](https://amqey.herokuapp.com/shop/fashion)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You need to add `position: relative` to the `classes.card` className in order to make the button position absolute within the card.